# Exception occurs when button clicked inside my custom control

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have made a UWP custom templated control that contains a collection of ICommandBarElement, much like the standard CommandBar control. The problem is that as soon as I click on any of the AppBarButton contained in my CommandBar implementation, an unhandled exception occurs: "No such interface supported".

There is something I must doing wrong but I just can't see it. Here is the code for the custom control:

```
public sealed class MyCommandBarControl : ContentControl
{
    public MyCommandBarControl()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyCommandBarControl);

        this.PrimaryCommands = new ObservableCollection<ICommandBarElement>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ICommandBarElement> PrimaryCommands
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<ICommandBarElement>)GetValue(PrimaryCommandsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PrimaryCommandsProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// PrimaryCommands Dependency Property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PrimaryCommandsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "PrimaryCommands",
            typeof(ObservableCollection<ICommandBarElement>),
            typeof(MainPage),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, null));


    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        var primaryItemsControl = GetTemplateChild("PrimaryItemsControl") as ItemsControl;
        primaryItemsControl.ItemsSource = this.PrimaryCommands;

    }

}
```

And the associated Style:

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyCommandBarControl" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyCommandBarControl">
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                          Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                          Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}">

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <ContentControl
                              x:Name="ContentControl"
                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                              ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                              Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                              HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                              VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                             IsTabStop="False"
                             Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"/>

                        <ItemsControl 
                              x:Name="PrimaryItemsControl"
                              IsTabStop="False"
                              Grid.Column="1"
                              Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Right"  
                              HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have made a [small project you can download](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=842BCFB537C257D7!21632&authkey=!ANFD9P4BnHiaNJc&ithint=file%2Czip) that reproduces the problem. Any help resolving this exception would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why not inherit from CommandBar control, and don't need to manage the PrimaryCommands by ourselves.

So simply change your code to the following can solve the issue:

```
public sealed class MyCommandBarControl : CommandBar
{
    public MyCommandBarControl()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyCommandBarControl);

        //this.PrimaryCommands = new ObservableCollection<ICommandBarElement>();
    }

    //public ObservableCollection<ICommandBarElement> PrimaryCommands
    //{
    //    get { return (ObservableCollection<ICommandBarElement>)GetValue(PrimaryCommandsProperty); }
    //    set { SetValue(PrimaryCommandsProperty, value); }
    //}

    ///// <summary>
    ///// PrimaryCommands Dependency Property
    ///// </summary>
    //public static readonly DependencyProperty PrimaryCommandsProperty =
    //    DependencyProperty.Register(
    //        "PrimaryCommands",
    //        typeof(ObservableCollection<ICommandBarElement>),
    //        typeof(MainPage),
    //        new PropertyMetadata(null, null));


    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        var primaryItemsControl = GetTemplateChild("PrimaryItemsControl") as ItemsControl;
        primaryItemsControl.ItemsSource = this.PrimaryCommands;

    }

}
```

**[Update1]**

I think there is underlying type conversion we cannot see or we have to use some interfaces like ICommandBar but we cannot use due to its protection level.

If you do hope to implement CommandBar by yourself, I think it's better to create your own Command button instead of using AppBarButton. **But you need to make sure you have a solid reason to do it by yourself.**

For example, the following will work if I use a default Button.

```
public sealed class MyCommandBarControl : ContentControl
{
    public MyCommandBarControl()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyCommandBarControl);

        this.PrimaryCommands = new ObservableCollection<Button>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Button> PrimaryCommands
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Button>)GetValue(PrimaryCommandsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PrimaryCommandsProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// PrimaryCommands Dependency Property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PrimaryCommandsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "PrimaryCommands",
            typeof(ObservableCollection<Button>),
            typeof(MainPage),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, null));


    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        var primaryItemsControl = GetTemplateChild("PrimaryItemsControl") as ItemsControl;
        primaryItemsControl.ItemsSource = this.PrimaryCommands;

    }

}
```

In MainPage.xaml

```
    <local:MyCommandBarControl>
        <local:MyCommandBarControl.Content>
            <TextBlock Text="My CommandBar" />
        </local:MyCommandBarControl.Content>

        <local:MyCommandBarControl.PrimaryCommands>
            <Button Content="Pin" Click="PinBarButton_Click" />
            <Button Content="UnPin" />
            <Button Content="Sync"  />
            <Button Content="Remove" />
        </local:MyCommandBarControl.PrimaryCommands>
    </local:MyCommandBarControl>
```

Comment: Weird - I'm using *AppBarButtons* outside *CommandBar* and they are working without issues. Do you have any more details about not using those controls in other places than command bar?

Comment: You are right. It can be used outside CommandBar. Actually, I mean the PrimaryCommands collection. I believe there is a way to do what OP wants, so I am still investigating on this. I have no access to the source code, so still don't know what kind of mystery behind it. will update if I find anything.

Comment: I've also tried to use *IObservableVector* instead of collection (like original PrimaryCommands), but it results in the same exception. I wonder what kind of interface it's looking for.

Comment: @Alan Yao: I started by inheriting CommandBar but I could not change the behavior enough to suit my need. Basicaly, I need something like the secondaryCommands popup menu but without the open/close behavior that toggle the IsCompact property of every primaryCommands  AppButtons. I taught it will be simpler to do a custom control. Thanks for the workaround but I am not sure I want to implement my own AppBar button at this point.