# Unknown error in Custom Control using AppBarButton

Tags: c#, xaml, exception, custom-controls, win-universal-app

I'm writing an app for UWP using C# and have come across a strange error that I can't seem to fix. When I put an ***AppBarButton*** inside an ***ItemsControl*** and click it, it causes an error.

This happens whether I bind the ***AppBarButton*** or put it in manually. This happens even if I put it in a clean Custom Control. It doesn't happen if I don't put the ***ItemsControl*** inside a Custom Control. It also doesn't happen if I put the ***AppBarButton*** inside a ***StackPanel*** or a ***Listview***.

Here is the error I get:
In a popup box:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFBFF3BCE8B (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in TorahScrollMVVM.exe: 0xC000027B: An application-internal exception has occurred (parameters: 0x000002A44F259E30, 0x0000000000000001).

and when I Break:
[image: error]

My XAML is simply:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:CustomControl1">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:CustomControl1">
                <ItemsControl>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Target"/>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Anyone have any idea what is happening?

Thanks

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store/windows-store-crashes-with-exception-code/11cc9422-165f-4cf7-9525-2153d7e54de9

Comment: @Gusman Could you be more specific. I tried the troubleshooter if that's what you meant. It didn't find anything wrong.

Comment: This is the error: No such interface supported. There is a similar question on SO, which you can have a look: [Exception occurs when button clicked inside my custom control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33508244/exception-occurs-when-button-clicked-inside-my-custom-control), this is possible a bug. BUT, you can use a `Button` controls to replace the `AppBarButton`.